# If $f(x) =ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is a cubic equation with roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma.$ Is there a way to find $\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, roots-of-cubics

Suppose $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is a cubic equation with roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma.$ Then we have:

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma= -\frac{b}{a}\quad (1)$

$\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha = \frac{c}{a}\quad (2)$

$\alpha\beta\gamma = -\frac{d}{a}\quad (3)$

We can find $\alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha + \alpha^2\gamma + \gamma^2\beta + \beta^2\alpha$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$ with the formula:

$$ \alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha + \alpha^2\gamma + \gamma^2\beta + \beta^2\alpha = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma) - 3\alpha\beta\gamma $$
$$=\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right) \left(\frac{c}{a}\right) - 3\left(-\frac{d}{a}\right).$$

But I was wondering if there was some way to find $ \alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha\ $ and therefore also $\ \alpha^2\gamma + \gamma^2\beta + \beta^2\alpha\ $ in terms of $a,b,c,d,\ $ with some algebraic manipulation, i.e. without [finding the roots with a cubic formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)?

Notice that there are *two* possible values of $\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha,$ namely $\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha = \beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha+\alpha^2\beta = \gamma^2\alpha+\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma$ and $\alpha^2\gamma+\gamma^2\beta+\beta^2\alpha = \gamma^2\beta+\beta^2\alpha+\alpha^2\gamma = \beta^2\alpha + \alpha^2\gamma+\gamma^2\beta.$

Comment: $\alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha$ depends on how $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are associated to the roots. For example, when the roots are $1$, $2$ and $3$, the expression is either $23$ or $25$. It seems that there are only two possible values for $\alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha$.

Comment: @Taladris I agree, but I don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: That expression isn't symmetric wrt the roots, hence unless the roots are all identical, it's value will depend on how you order/name the roots. Thus there's no way to find a unique value in general for that.

Comment: Why does an expression have to be symmetric in order for you to be able to find the value of it?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I don't know how to answer your question. I commented to clarify the question.

Comment: @Macavity: the expressions can take at most two values (you can change one to the other via a transposition $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \mapsto (\beta,\alpha,\gamma)$), so it is not that bad. I don't know how to compute the values of these two expressions though

Comment: @Taladris You're right, cyclic symmetry implies exactly two values are possible.  Sum of those two values and product of those two values are symmetric functions, so technically we can find these two from just the coefficients as roots of a single quadratic.

Comment: Not only can you not find the value you desire without finding the cube roots, you can't find them even if you *have* the roots. There's no natural order to the roots. The value of $\alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha$ depends on which root *you* assign to each Greek letter. You can find the whole sum (all six terms) because every choice of two roots for $m^2n$ is used.

Comment: @EricSnyder but we can find the two values of the two different expressions. And if we can find the value of one of the expressions, then we can immediately find the value of the other one because $\alpha^2\gamma + \gamma^2\beta + \beta^2\alpha =  \alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha + \alpha^2\gamma + \gamma^2\beta + \beta^2\alpha - (\alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha).$ It doesn't matter which one we find first. I want to find the value of both expressions.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I suppose you can do that calculation if you know the roots and can assign each root to a letter. Think about it this way: let's say we go ahead and calculate the three roots via the horrific order-3 equations that no one has memorized. Which of these three numbers is $\alpha$? We can't know until we make that assignment of letter to root. Which means we can't extract that information without having the roots computed.

Comment: I have found a way to find $ \alpha^2\beta + \beta^2\gamma + \gamma^2\alpha\ $ and therefore also $\ \alpha^2\gamma + \gamma^2\beta + \beta^2\alpha\ $ in terms of $a,b,c,d,\ $ although it is not exactly pretty, but it is what I was looking for. Solution to be posted shortly. Edit: Jyrki Lahtonen beat me to it!

Comment: I think that the question is a duplicate of [this older one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731083/11619). I am very sorry about unwittingly answering it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes that is an exact duplicate, which obviously I failed to find when seraching for one earlier.. I've voted to close. Feel free to do the same.

Comment: @AdamRubinson If you agree, then it's fine. I have a relevant dupehammer, so my vote results in an instant closure. That's why I waited with my vote. Anyway, sorry about not finding it before answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know the elementary symmetric polynomials evaluated at the roots (by the Vieta relations):
$$
\begin{aligned}s_1&=\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-b/a,\\
s_2&=\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=c/a,\\
s_3&=\alpha\beta\gamma=-d/a.
\end{aligned}
$$
The fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials says that every symmetric polynomial can be written in terms of the elementary ones.

You are interested in finding
$$
\begin{aligned}
u&=\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha,&\text{or}\\
v&=\alpha^2\gamma+\gamma^2\beta+\beta^2\alpha.
\end{aligned}
$$
The problem, as explained by the others, is that you cannot tell which is which because $u$ and $v$ only follow cyclic symmetry.

However, the combinations $u+v$ and $uv$ are fully symmetric. A banal (but a bit tedious) calculation  shows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
u+v&=s_1s_2-3s_3,\\
uv&=s_1^3s_3-6s_1s_2s_3+s_2^3+s_3^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
This means that we know the coefficients of the quadratic polynomial
$$
p(x)=(x-u)(x-v)=x^2-[u+v]x+uv
$$
that has $u$ and $v$ as its roots. All you need to do is plug in the known values of $s_1,s_2,s_3$ into the formulas above, and solve the quadratic $p(x)=0$. The roots are the two choices.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I just found also. I also used the letters $u$ and $v$ in my calculations. Great minds think alike!

Comment: Not entirely unexpectedly, a second round of searching located a duplicate. Wonder what I did wrong the first time :-(

Answer (score 2):

A function of two or more variables is said to be symmetric function if $f$ remains unaltered by an interchange of any two of it's variables.

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are roots of a cubic equation and the function $f$ of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ is invariant under the permutations of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, then we call $f$ , a symmetric function of roots.

Let us consider a function

$f(x, y, z) =x^2y+y^2x+z^2x+x^2z+y^2z+z^2y$

Then $f$ is a symmetric function of the roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Here comes the nice formula

$\sum_{\text{sym}} \alpha^2\beta= \sum_{\text{sym}} \alpha
  \sum_{\text{sym}} \alpha\beta-3\alpha\beta\gamma$

---

Now consider the function

$f(x, y, z) =x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$

Then $f$ is not a symmetric function of the roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

The values of $f$ changes along with the permutations of the roots.

Hence  $\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha$ may have  different values.

---

$f(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) =\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha$  have two different vaues for distinct values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. One for all even permutations and other for all odd permutations.

For even permutations :

$f(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) =f(\beta, \gamma, \alpha) =f(\gamma, \alpha, \beta) $

For odd permutations :

$f(\alpha, \gamma, \beta) =f(\beta, \alpha, \gamma) =f(\gamma, \beta, \alpha) $

But still the sum depends on the choice of the order of the roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but given three numbers $x,y,z,\ $ doesn't $ \vert \{ a^2b + b^2c + c^2a : a,b,c \in \{x,y,z\}, a\neq b, b\neq c, c\neq a \} \vert  = 2 ?$ In other words, for your function $f$, $f(x,y,z) = f(y,z,x) = f(z,x,y)$ and $f(z,y,x) = f(y,x,z) = f(x,z,y).$

Comment: No you don't: you have $2$ possible values because $2^23 + 3^24 + 4^22 = 3^24 + 4^22 + 2^23 = 4^22 + 2^23 + 3^24$ etc... Is your function $f$ accidentally wrong by the way?

Comment: Yes.$ f(x, y, z) =x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$. Now I have corrected.

Comment: Do you agree now that you can only have two possible values?

Answer (score 1):

Quantity is not-symmetric. This results in rather complex formula:

$$\alpha^2\beta+\beta^2\gamma+\gamma^2\alpha=t_{1}\,t_{3}^2-{{b\,t_{3}^2}\over{3\,a}}+t_{2}^2\,t_{3}-{{2\,b\,
 t_{2}\,t_{3}}\over{3\,a}}-{{2\,b\,t_{1}\,t_{3}}\over{3\,a}}+\\{{b^2\,
 t_{3}}\over{3\,a^2}}-{{b\,t_{2}^2}\over{3\,a}}+t_{1}^2\,t_{2}-{{2\,b
 \,t_{1}\,t_{2}}\over{3\,a}}+{{b^2\,t_{2}}\over{3\,a^2}}-{{b\,t_{1}^2
 }\over{3\,a}}+{{b^2\,t_{1}}\over{3\,a^2}}-{{b^3}\over{9\,a^3}}$$

$$t_i=\sqrt[3]{\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}-\frac{p^3}{27}}}\,e^{k_i\frac{2i\pi}{3}}+\frac{p}{3\sqrt[3]{\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}-\frac{p^3}{27}}}}e^{-k_i\frac{2i\pi}{3}}, i\in\{1,2,3\}$$

$$p={{b^2}\over{3\,a^2}}-{{c}\over{a}}, q={{b\,c
 }\over{3\,a^2}}-{{d}\over{a}}-{{2\,b^3}\over{27\,a^3}}$$

$\{k_1,k_2,k_3\}=\{0,1,2\}$ determines order of roots taken as $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$.